# Two buttons doesnt work?

Tags: ios, xcode, button

I'm trying to but two 'Buttons' like the picture below but it gives me an error as you see, when I add the Constants (Add Missing Constants).

Can anyone help?

```
2016-02-08 16:29:03.689 XXXX

[572:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to create description in descriptionForLayoutAttribute_layoutItem_coefficient. Something is nil'

*** First throw call stack:(0x2e54ef83 0x38cffccf 0x2e54eec5 0x2efe439f 0x2efe41b3 0x2efe45e5 0x2e4c8a0b 0x2ee6c1c5 0x2e524edb 0x2e494611 0x2e4bcc03 0x2ee7b19f 0x2ee7b137 0x312f8aad 0x2eedb671 0x2eebce27 0x2eeb85fd 0x2eeb823b 0x2eeb5f6d 0x30e5bae5 0x30e5b93d 0x30e5b8b7 0x30e5b7bb 0x30e65217 0x2eeb5b2b 0x30e65187 0x30e614ed 0x312f81ab 0x30e5faa9 0x2e4828f1 0x312f8145 0x30e5faa9 0x2e4828f1 0x312f8145 0x30e5faa9 0x2e4828f1 0x312f8145 0x30e5faa9 0x2e4828f1 0x312f8145 0x30e5faa9 0x2e4828f1 0x312f8145 0x30e5faa9 0x2e4828f1 0x312f8145 0x30e5faa9 0x2e4828f1 0x312f8145 0x30e5faa9 0x2e4828f1 0x312f8145 0x30e5faa9 0x2e4828f1 0x312f8145 0x30e5faa9 0x2eeb5b2b 0x30e79915 0x30de85eb 0x309e962b 0x309e4e3b 0x309e4ccd 0x309e46df 0x309e44ef 0x309de21d 0x2e51a255 0x2e517bf9 0x2e517f3b 0x2e482ebf 0x2e482ca3 0x33388663 0x30dcf14d 0x51acd 0x3920cab7)libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException(lldb)
```

[image]

Comment: You mean "Constraints", not "Constants", I guess?

Comment: Clear all constraints and check if the error disappear, after that, try again adding the missing constraints.

Comment: Google didn't translate it well :)

Comment: If you search for "descriptionForLayoutAttribute_layoutItem_coefficient", there are some similar questions with answers that may help you.

Comment: I cleaned it and did it four times, same error!

Comment: Phillip Mils I'll look for it

Comment: Okay, I looked, didn't understand :/ can I get away from 'Add Missing Constraints' and add both of them manually? can anyone tell me what to add for Button 1 and Button 2? here the picture http://oi65.tinypic.com/2a6mezb.jpg